# Can I save input from form to .txt in HTML, using JAVASCRIPT/jQuery, and then use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

Is it possible to save textinput (locally) from a form to a textfile, and then open that document to use it later on?

Just using HTML, javascript and jQuery. No databases or php.

/W

Comment: Wrong approach. Even if possible, that's not the purpose of web pages.

Comment: The answer to this varies depending on if you mean server side or client side

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to save only if the user allow it to be saved just like a download and he must open it manually, the only issue is to suggest a name, my sample code will suggest a name only for Google Chome and only if you use a link instead of button because of the `download` attribute.

You will only need a [base64 encode library](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) and JQuery to easy things.

```js
// This will generate the text file content based on the form data
function buildData(){
  var txtData = "Name: "+$("#nameField").val()+
      "\r\nLast Name: "+$("#lastNameField").val()+
      "\r\nGender: "+($("#genderMale").is(":checked")?"Male":"Female");

  return txtData;
}
// This will be executed when the document is ready
$(function(){
  // This will act when the submit BUTTON is clicked
  $("#formToSave").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var txtData = buildData();
    window.location.href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData);
  });

  // This will act when the submit LINK is clicked
  $("#submitLink").click(function(event){
    var txtData = buildData();
    $(this).attr('download','sugguestedName.txt')
      .attr('href',"data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
        <dl>
            <dt>Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="nameField" value="Sample" /></dd>
            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" id="lastNameField" value="Last Name" /></dd>
            <dt>Gender:</dt>
            <dd><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="M" id="genderMale" />
                Male
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="F" />
                Female
        </dl>
        <p><a href="javascript://Save as TXT" id="submitLink">Save as TXT</a></p>
        <p><button type="submit"><img src="http://www.suttonrunners.org/images/save_icon.gif" alt=""/> Save as TXT</button></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**BEST solution if you ask me is this.**
This will save the file with the file name of your choice and automatically in HTML or in TXT at your choice with buttons.

**Example:**

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

function addTextHTML()
{
    document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".html"
}

function addTextTXT()
{
    document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".txt"
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">

    <textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="text" placeholder="Type your text here:"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="File Name">
    <input type="submit" onClick="addTextHTML();" value="Save As HTML">
    <input type="submit" onClick="addTexttxt();" value="Save As TXT">

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, You have to save a user's input locally to a text file.

Check this link. See if this helps.

[Saving user input to a text file locally](http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/)

Answer (score 2):

This will work to both load and save a file into TXT from a HTML page with a save as choice

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
        <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to save the data for later use, but you can not save to a *file* using JavaScript (in the browser).

To be comprehensive:
You can not store something into a file using JavaScript in the Browser, but [using HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), you can read files.

Comment: Please read the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save it as local file without using server side logic. But if that fits your needs, you could look at local storage of html5 or us a javascript plugin as [jStorage](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Or this will work too the same way but without a save as choice:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
(function () {
var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };


  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();

}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> <button id="create">Create file</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>


  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "qm5AG"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Answer is YES

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function WriteToFile()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\NewFile.txt", true);
var text=document.getElementById("TextArea1").innerText;
s.WriteLine(text);
s.WriteLine('***********************');
s.Close();
}
</script>

<form name="abc">
<textarea name="text">FIFA</textarea>
<button onclick="WriteToFile()">Click to save</Button>  
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... and this will work only with InternetExplorer, and only if security settings allow it.

Comment: I only see ActiveXObject; I take it this is IE only?

Comment: correct! and note it is very insecure to allow this functionality