# is there a way to save html form data with out web server or use of php?

Tags: html

This is an example of the code i have.  there are multiple data fields that need saved and n seperate lines so the data is legible.

```
enter code here

<html>
<body>
<center>

<font size="2" face="arial" color="#CF18DC">
* Required Field</font></center>
<center><form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" accept-                   charset="UTF-8">

<tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <center><strong><font color="#CF18DC">* </font>/Member #:                     </strong>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" name="field-885d025b2e34341" id="field-885d025b2e34341" size="40" value="" />

        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value=" Submit Form " />
    </td>
</table>
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

i need a submit function or something to save the form data to a txt file in a local directory.  I just cant figure this out can anyone please help?  The file name that saves has to be the answer received in one of the collected data fields or it will just over write the file each time.  Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I save input from form to .txt in HTML, using JAVASCRIPT/jQuery, and then use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You will need some sort of contraption on the server side in order to write data to a source.

it does not have to be PHP. It can be any number of things; PHP, Python, Node.js, Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should easily be able to do this with some Javascript/Jquery. I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but I'm going on a hunch.

[See htmlNewbie's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us).

Hope this helps.