# Can I read the input from a HTML form and save it at at a specific position in TXT file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used this as reference: 
[Can I save input from form to .txt in HTML, using JAVASCRIPT/jQuery, and then use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us)

Can I save input from form to .txt in HTML, using JAVASCRIPT/jQuery, and then use it?. But that is intended for client side and I want server side.

I have a TXT file with this content:

```
PAGE=1
until [ $PAGE -gt 9 ]; do
wget "http://www.example.com/INPUT-WORD-HERE/page_0"$PAGE".jpg"
let PAGE+=1
done

PAGE=10
until [ $PAGE -gt 99 ]; do
wget "http://www.example.com/INPUT-WORD-HERE/page_"$PAGE".jpg"
let PAGE+=1
done
```

Is it possible for me to read the input from a HTML form and save it at a specific position in this TXT file (hosting). The specific position is INPUT-WORD-HERE. So, the idea would be to replace all the INPUT-WORD-HERE  with the HTML input.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow to read and write files to clients computer. If you want store data on server you can use server side language like PHP, Node.js or ASP.NET

Comment: Is this txt file located on clients computer?

Comment: I store txt file in server to use later.

Comment: What language are you using (the code above)? Because it doesn't look like JavaScript, PHP or HTML

Comment: Sent input data to server using GET or POST, then write/append/replace text in file

Comment: Thank for your sugest to Matjaz Mav. Can you write a little example code for me? thank.s

Comment: For Alvaro Montoro, the code above is bash script for me to download image from web.

Comment: Are you going to modify a bash script with user input, and then run that script on your server? That sounds potentially dangerous

Comment: This script only for me, not for common user.

Comment: Why did you edit out the link? If it's your reference, it should be a link to make life easier for people trying to help you (right now you force them to copy and past, and it's less readable)

Answer (score 1):

So from what you describe, this is what should be done (I used PHP for the code as you tagged your question with it):

1. Open your batch file as a string.

   ```
   $fileTXT = file_get_contents($path_to_your_file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
   ```

   (Replace `$path_to_your_file` with the relative path to the file that you want to update)
2. Replace all the instances of INPUT-WORD-HERE with the new input:

   ```
   $fileTXT = str_replace("INPUT-WORD-HERE", $textToReplace, $fileTXT);
   ```

   But it is not that simple. This is a bit trickier than what it seems initially, as INPUT-WORD-HERE will not be the same text from one time to another. We need to create a generic script that will replace whatever the value is:

   ```
   $pos1 = strpos($fileTXT, "http://www.example.com/");
   $textFrom = substr($fileTXT, $pos1+23, strpos($fileTXT, "/", $pos1 + 23) - $pos1 - 23);
   $fileTXT = str_replace("http://www.example.com/" . $textFrom . "/", "http://www.example.com/" . $textTo . "/", $fileTXT);
   ```

   I replace the whole URL, to avoid possible problems if the previous INPUT-WORD-HERE value matched a different text in the file (e.g.: "example" or "PAGE")
3. Save the file.

   ```
   file_put_contents($path_to_your_file, $fileTXT);
   ```

---

The final code would look like:

```
<?php

// here the relative path to your batch file
$filename = "myfile.txt";
// replace $_GET["txt"] for the name of the input that will have the new value. You can use $_POST too
$textTo = $_GET["txt"];

// read the content of the file into a string
$fileTXT = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

// get the word to be replace from the URL (23 is the length of "http://www.example.com/", you'll need to change that number to fit the URL that you place there)
$pos1 = strpos($fileTXT, "http://www.example.com/");
$textFrom = substr($fileTXT, $pos1+23, strpos($fileTXT, "/", $pos1 + 23) - $pos1 - 23);
$fileTXT = str_replace("http://www.example.com/" . $textFrom . "/", "http://www.example.com/" . $textTo . "/", $fileTXT);

// overwrite the content of the file
file_put_contents($filename, $fileTXT);
```

As I specified in the comments, **this solution presents some dangers and should not be used with common users** (you said it was Ok, as it was only for you). If you change it so common users can access it, you should preprocess and sanitize the input.

---

As requested by the user, this is a simple example of how the HTML form could be:

```
<form method="get" action="YOUR_PHP_FILE_WITH_THE_ABOVE_CODE">
    <label for="txt">
        Write here the new name:
        <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Make Changes" />
</form>
```

You just need to make sure that the text input has the same name as the parameter that you read in the `$_GET` (or in the `$_POST`, but then you'd need to change the form to `method="post"`).

Comment: Thank for your answer Mr Alvaro Montoro.

Comment: I had difficulty making the forms , can you add model the input form? thank

Comment: I added a small example of a form that would work with the PHP