# How to save html page content in .txt file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have create a static html page for quiz. 
Following is my code

```
<style>
    body {
font-family: Open Sans;
}
#quiz {display:none;}
#prev {display:none;}
#start {display:none;}
#submit{display:none;}
ul{list-style:outside none none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.question>div>div>div>p{    color: #fff;
background-color: #337ab7;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 3px;}
.navbar-default {background-color: #fff;border-color: #ddd; border-radius:0px;}
</style>
<body>
<div class='container question'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col col-md-12' id='quiz'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='container question' >
<div class='row' id='quiz'>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class='container'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default pull-right' id='next'>Next</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default pull-left' id='prev'>Prev</a> 
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default' id='start'>Start Over</a>


        <div class='button' id='submit' style='display:none;'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Name' id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"/>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    function saveTextAsFile()
    {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("question").text;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
    }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    }

    function loadFileAsText()
    {
        var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
            var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
    }

                (function() {
      var questions = [
      {
        question: "Which one is correct?",
        choices: ['a!=b', 'a=!b', 'a:=b', 'a=-b'],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      ];

      var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
      var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
      var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

      // Display initial question
      displayNext();

      // Click handler for the 'next' button
      $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Suspend click listener during fade animation
        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
          return false;
        }
        choose();

        // If no user selection, progress is stopped
        if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
          alert('Please make a selection!');
        } else {
          questionCounter++;
          displayNext();
        }
      });

      // Click handler for the 'prev' button
      $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
          return false;
        }
        choose();
        questionCounter--;
        displayNext();
      });

      // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
      $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
          return false;
        }
        questionCounter = 0;
        selections = [];
        displayNext();
        $('#start').hide();
      });

      // Animates buttons on hover
      $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
      $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });

      // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
      // the answer selections
      function createQuestionElement(index) {
        var qElement = $('<div>', {
          id: 'question'
        });

        var header = $('<p>Question ' + (index + 1)  + '</p>');
        qElement.append(header);

        var question = $('<h3>').append(questions[index].question);
        qElement.append(question);

        var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
        qElement.append(radioButtons);

        return qElement;
      }

      // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
      function createRadios(index) {
        var radioList = $('<ul>');
        var item;
        var input = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
          item = $('<li>');
          input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
          input += questions[index].choices[i];
          item.append(input);
          radioList.append(item);
        }
        return radioList;
      }

      // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
      function choose() {
        selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
      }

      // Displays next requested element
      function displayNext() {
        quiz.fadeOut(function() {
          $('#question').remove();

          if(questionCounter < questions.length){
            var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
            quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
            if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
              $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
            }

            // Controls display of 'prev' button
            if(questionCounter === 1){
              $('#prev').show();
            } else if(questionCounter === 0){

              $('#prev').hide();
              $('#next').show();
            }
          }else {
            var scoreElem = displayScore();
            quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
            $('#next').hide();
            $('#prev').hide();
            $('#start').show();
            $('#submit').show();
          }
        });
      }

      // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
      function displayScore() {
        var score = $('<h4>',{id: 'question'});

        var numCorrect = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
          if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
            numCorrect++;
          }
        }

        score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                     questions.length + ' right!!!');
        return score;
      }
    })();


    </script>
        </body>
```

all is working fine but i want to save the checked radio button value and final result in .txt file
i want to save all the answers by user and along with the correct and the wrong to.

Comment: save all reponses by using <checkboxrefence>.value; to array and then final score ?

Comment: can you give me the code

Comment: nope , sorry. the code you posted is giving me the creeps, i cant read it :))

Comment: Here what I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us

Comment: **try this link** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us

Comment: try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685263/can-i-save-input-from-form-to-txt-in-html-using-javascript-jquery-and-then-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to note :
 - initialize the variable `textToSave` first with no value;
 - `document.getElementById("question").text;` Should be `document.getElementById("question").innerHTML;`
 - in the body of `choose`, add the value of radio to the variable `textToSave`

And the result

```js
var textToSave='';
function saveTextAsFile()
    {
   textToSave += ". Final Result : "+document.getElementById("question").innerHTML;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
    }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    }

    function loadFileAsText()
    {
        var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
            var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
    }

                (function() {
      var questions = [
      {
        question: "Which one is correct?",
        choices: ['a!=b', 'a=!b', 'a:=b', 'a=-b'],
        correctAnswer: 0
      },

      ];

      var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
      var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
      var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

      // Display initial question
      displayNext();

      // Click handler for the 'next' button
      $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Suspend click listener during fade animation
        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
          return false;
        }
        choose();

        // If no user selection, progress is stopped
        if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
          alert('Please make a selection!');
        } else {
          questionCounter++;
          displayNext();
        }
      });

      // Click handler for the 'prev' button
      $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
          return false;
        }
        choose();
        questionCounter--;
        displayNext();
      });

      // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
      $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
          return false;
        }
        questionCounter = 0;
        selections = [];
        displayNext();
        $('#start').hide();
      });

      // Animates buttons on hover
      $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
      $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });

      // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
      // the answer selections
      function createQuestionElement(index) {
        var qElement = $('<div>', {
          id: 'question'
        });

        var header = $('<p>Question ' + (index + 1)  + '</p>');
        qElement.append(header);

        var question = $('<h3>').append(questions[index].question);
        qElement.append(question);

        var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
        qElement.append(radioButtons);

        return qElement;
      }

      // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
      function createRadios(index) {
        var radioList = $('<ul>');
        var item;
        var input = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
          item = $('<li>');
          input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
          input += questions[index].choices[i];
          item.append(input);
          radioList.append(item);
        }
        return radioList;
      }

      // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
      function choose() {
        selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
        textToSave += "Choosen Value : "+selections[questionCounter];
      }

      // Displays next requested element
      function displayNext() {
        quiz.fadeOut(function() {
          $('#question').remove();

          if(questionCounter < questions.length){
            var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
            quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
            if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
              $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
            }

            // Controls display of 'prev' button
            if(questionCounter === 1){
              $('#prev').show();
            } else if(questionCounter === 0){

              $('#prev').hide();
              $('#next').show();
            }
          }else {
            var scoreElem = displayScore();
            quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
            $('#next').hide();
            $('#prev').hide();
            $('#start').show();
            $('#submit').show();
          }
        });
      }

      // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
      function displayScore() {
        var score = $('<h4>',{id: 'question'});

        var numCorrect = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
          if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
            numCorrect++;
          }
        }

        score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                     questions.length + ' right!!!');
        return score;
      }
    })();
```

```html
<style>
    body {
font-family: Open Sans;
}
#quiz {display:none;}
#prev {display:none;}
#start {display:none;}
#submit{display:none;}
ul{list-style:outside none none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.question>div>div>div>p{    color: #fff;
background-color: #337ab7;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 3px;}
.navbar-default {background-color: #fff;border-color: #ddd; border-radius:0px;}
</style>
<body>
<div class='container question'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col col-md-12' id='quiz'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='container question' >
<div class='row' id='quiz'>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class='container'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default pull-right' id='next'>Next</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default pull-left' id='prev'>Prev</a> 
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-md btn-default' id='start'>Start Over</a>


        <div class='button' id='submit' style='display:none;'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Name' id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"/>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to save the data for yourself, not the end user.

If you are looking to generate a txt file and download it - You can refer answer from Sagar V.

You can't directly save your answers or whatever data into a file by using JavaScript from a web browser.

You neeed a small server, maybe in node.js , php or java
First format your answers in particular structure like json and sene it as POST request method parameter

In server parse your parameter and save to an file you need

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadFile(filename, content) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```